# Elasticsearch 6.3 - How to enable SSL in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Any idea how to enable https in elastic search. Give me the steps to understand by developer

Answer (score 2):

You can specify SSL options for any output that supports SSL. You can also specify SSL options when you set up the Kibana endpoint.

Example output config with SSL enabled:

```
output.elasticsearch.hosts: ["192.168.1.42:9200"]
output.elasticsearch.ssl.certificate_authorities: ["/etc/pki/root/ca.pem"]
output.elasticsearch.ssl.certificate: "/etc/pki/client/cert.pem"
output.elasticsearch.ssl.key: "/etc/pki/client/cert.key"
```

Example Kibana endpoint config with SSL enabled:

```
setup.kibana.host: "192.0.2.255:5601"
setup.kibana.protocol: "https"
setup.kibana.ssl.enabled: true
setup.kibana.ssl.certificate_authorities: ["/etc/pki/root/ca.pem"]
setup.kibana.ssl.certificate: "/etc/pki/client/cert.pem"
setup.kibana.ssl.key: "/etc/pki/client/cert.key
```

you can go through official documentation from this link :) : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/server/current/configuration-ssl.html

Comment: how to generate cert.pem and cert.key. is it default in system ?

Comment: yes file is in system, or you can try alternate approach by modifying elasticsearch.yml file property as given on this link https://www.elastic.co/blog/getting-started-with-elasticsearch-ssl-native-authentication

Comment: where to configure output.elasticsearch.hosts ...  and  setup.kibana.host:

Comment: I couldn't find the path "/etc/pki/client" - I walkthrough the documention, it is keep on navigate to another link and another link is going on .. guide how to setup